# Why does PrintStream inherit from byte streams?

Tags: java, io, stream, character, bytestream

As far as I know `java.io` ist divided into byte streams and character streams.
Byte streams for reading and writing bytes and character streams for reading and writing characters.

`PrintStream` has following inheritance hierarchy:

```
Object <- OutputStream <- FilterOutputStream <- PrintStream.
```

Thus I made resolution that `PrintStream` related with reading and writing bytes.

But if write something like this:

```
    PrintStream output = new PrintStream(System.out);

    output.print(true);
    output.print((int) 123);
    output.print((float) 123.456);

    output.printf(Locale.UK, "Text + data: %1$d", 123);

    ...
```

I see *characters* in my console.
This situation confused me. Please clarify my misunderstanding.
What do the terms *byte stream* and *character stream* really mean?

Answer (score 2):

The `PrintStream` class is a semantic anomaly that exists for historical reasons.  The class existed in Java 1.0 before the Java designers recognized<sup>1</sup> the need to have different "stacks" for character and byte streams.  It represents "the original way" to do simple text output in Java ... before `Writer` and its subtypes were introduced in Java 1.1.

So in fact, byte stream and character stream (probably) mean exactly what they seem to you to mean.  At any rate, what they mean is best described in the Java Tutorial:

- [Byte Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html).
- [Character Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html).

---

<sup>1 - They probably realised the need earlier, but there were overriding "commercial reasons" to get Java 1.0 released quickly.</sup>

Comment: I found out it after in test I encounter the question about **System.setOut()** Ultimately I should to know argument type for right answer. I suggested that it is Writer because I know that **System.out.println** writes characters but my logic was wrong!